# How can you calculate the delta-v for a Hohmann transfer using potential gravitational energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

I've been trying to calculate the delta-v required for a Hohmann transfer. I simply assume that, as no loss of energy happens on a vacuum, all you need to calculate is the sum of potential $(-GMm/r)$ + kinetic energy $(GMm/r)$, which is the total mechanical energy at each height of the orbit, subtract the difference and then convert it all to velocity with $mv^2/2$.

Is my train of thought correct, or am I missing some important info here? because I have been getting multiple inconsistent results, and I'm feeling kinda lost :(

Comment: From Kerbal space program, [MechJeb2](https://ksp.sarbian.com/jenkins/job/MechJeb2-Dev/) autopilot can calculate all these things (in a fictional setting).  If you can decypher code, check out TransferCalculator.cs and maybe OperationInterplanetaryTransfer.cs from [here](https://ksp.sarbian.com/jenkins/job/MechJeb2-Dev/ws/MechJeb2/Maneuver/)  I wish I knew more about this to help you myself.  Rocket Science! Yeah!

Comment: @Brian This is a *mainstream physics* forum.  Please do not provide comments linking to material on games or alternate physics.

Comment: @StephenG KSP is a (gamified) orbital simulation engine, which does a good job of implementing real newtonian dynamics. The constants are different, but the physics there is largely correct.

Comment: @jfinizolas Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty As there are plenty of actual physics references explaining these concepts it makes no sense to link to code that the OP is supposed to decypher to figure out their conceptual problem.  It's a physics concept and needs to be explained that way.

Comment: @StephenG That is true. But attacking KSP as "non-mainstream" only obscures that message under a layer of nonsense argumentation, making it *less* likely that the point will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a couple of things.

> all you need to calculate is the sum of potential $(-GMm/r)$ + kinetic energy $(GMm/r)$

This is incorrect: the potential and kinetic energies do not have the same magnitude in a circular orbit. (This would imply a constant total mechanical energy for all circular orbits, regardless of their height.) Instead, the kinetic energy is *half* the absolute value of the potential energy.

That said, if you try to just

> calculate [...] the total mechanical energy at each height of the orbit, subtract the difference and then convert it all to velocity with $mv^2/2$

you will get an incorrect result. This is because that calculation does not account for the fact that there are *two* independent burns. For collinear burns (i.e. firing along the instantaneous velocity) there is a one-to-one relationship between $\Delta v$ and the change in kinetic energy, but this relationship depends on how fast you're going to begin with.

(As a simple example, if you're going at $v_0=1$ and you speed up by $\Delta v=1$, then the specific kinetic energy increases by $\Delta\mathrm{sKE}=2^2-1^2=3$, whereas the same $\Delta v$ starting at $v_0=10$ produces a larger kinetic-energy increase of $\Delta\mathrm{sKE}=11^2-10^2=21$.)

That means that kinetic-energy change and $\Delta v$ are separate and independent measures. We care more about $\Delta v$ because that's the measure which matches the propellant use (and propellant budget) more closely. The Hohmann transfer orbit exploits this difference by splitting the propellant use into two separate burns, spending more $\Delta v$ on the first one (where the craft is going faster, so the $\Delta v$ spend gives you a higher kinetic energy increase) than on the second one.

That said, the general energetics idea is correct, once you break out the calculation into the two separate burns, using the energy of the Hohmann elliptical transfer orbit as the middle point. For the details, see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit#Calculation).

Answer (score 0):

The total energy of the initial and final orbits is different.

If you think about it the total energy of a circular orbit depends only on distance and is given by :

$$E = - \frac 1 2 \frac {GMm} r$$

So if you start and end with two circular orbits you cannot have them with the same energy unless they are the same orbital distance.

The delta-v you apply (which is done twice, of course) first changes the orbit from circular to ellipical and then from elliptical to circular.  Each of the three orbital path has a different energy.  When you apply delta-v you are changing the total energy of the object - that's the whole point of delta-v.